# Segue has no member ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard

I'm trying to learn basic iOS Swift3 and using the storyboard method. I was working through the code in [the tutorial on this website](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/).

Having created the storyboard links for FirstCustomSegue, I code as follows; I have added comments for all 6 errors:

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    // Value of type 'FirstCustomSegue' has no member 'sourceGameViewController'
    var firstVCView = self.sourceGameViewController.view as UIView!
    var secondVCView = self.destinationGameViewController.view as UIView!

    // Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIScreen'
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIApplication'
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    // Value of type 'FirstCustomSegue' has no member 'sourceGameViewController' (This is in the (Finished) line, of course)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

    }) { (Finished) -> Void inself.sourceGameViewController.presentGameViewController(self.destinationGameViewController as UIViewController,
                animated: false,
                completion: nil)
    }
}

}
```

Looks to me as though there's a missing connection somewhere, but I can't find it. Perhaps some of it is a change in iOS10? Some searching has suggested that this may be the problem with the UIScreen.mainScreen() bits, but I can't find anything that resolves the problems.

Comment: The tutorial you are following is iOS 8 which is coding in Swift 2.x. You on the other hand are coding in Swift 3. whenever you see this **Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIScreen** it means the thing you are calling **isn't** a function, so you should remove the `()`.  if you type `UIScreen.` and then start typing m...you will see it only has main as a property, NOT as a function. Same issue for your `UIApplicaton` it should be `UIApplication.shared`... a rule of the thumb is when you are using old tutorials, don't copy/paste, instead type and see if the sytanx is updated.

Comment: In addition the error of **Value of type 'FirstCustomSegue' has no member 'sourceGameViewController** means that your FirstCustomSegue **doesn't** have any *property*(also known as member) named `ViewController`. Perhaps you named your property something else and its a typo or don't any such property at ALL

Comment: Thank you -- that is immensely helpful. Now I know how to move forward with these things! Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code into Swift 3.0 style. But do you use Xcode 8? If you use Xcode 8, the compiler may help you to fix syntax errors.

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let firstVCView: UIView = self.source.view
        let secondVCView: UIView = self.destination.view

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        secondVCView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            firstVCView.frame = firstVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight)
            secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight)
        }, completion: { [unowned self] finished in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

You can also convert your code into latest Swift syntax by yourself.
**Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax...**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/niayG.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> UIApplication.shared

and

> UIScreen.main

in Swift 3. (Can't comment yet.)

Comment: This produces the same error message: "Cannot call value of non-function type X"

Comment: I copy pasted your class and renamed "UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width" to "UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width", it definitely compiles.